# Compare Names within the same column Excel

Tags: excel, grouping, normalization

I have 16 k rows of companies names in an Excel file. The list contains information from different data systems. That's why, we may have the same supplier with slightly different names.

My job is to "group" (normalize) this suppliers.

The issue is that I have all of them under one column. Therefore, I can't use fuzzy look-up add-in.

For example (it is shown as rows here, but it is actually under one single column):

What I have:

Apple / ADIDAS / DELL / Nike Inc. / Nike / Nike LLC / Xiaomi

What I want

Apple / ADIDAS / DELL / Nike / Xiaomi

Additionally, I have no other field in the list that can help me group the names in any way.

Any advise would be appreciated.

Regards,

Nangys

Comment: Use text to columns and split on spaces

Comment: The example is a simplified one; however, you gave me an idea. I could do exactly what you say and then create two table. One with the original data, and one with the first column of the text to column. After that, I could use the Fuzzy Look up. Thanks